# When did “eitel” switch from “vergänglich” (fading) to “eingebildet” (smug)?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, history

In the poem by Andreas Gryphius: [Alles ist eitel](http://poemhunter.com/poem/es-ist-alles-eitel/) written in the 16th century the adjective *eitel* stands for fading or fleeting.

However, today [Duden online says](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/eitel):

> selbstgefällig (smug), kokett (coquettish) und dandyhaft (dandy-like?)

I was wondering when this change did come about. Was it a continuous shift or is there a literary work to which this change can be pinned? Is there anything known about this at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ambiguity of *eitel* was already discussed in the 19th century [*Deutsches Wörterbuch*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GE03650#XGE03650) by the Grimm brothers. For the positive side of the word, they draw a line from its old meaning of pureness and its 14th/15th century usage as part of noble names:

> ***3)** unmittelbar verwandt ist* eitel *= lauter, rein* ... *In urkunden des 14. 15 jh. findet sich den eigennamen gräflicher und adlicher geschlechter verschiedentlich ein* 'itel' *oder* 'eitel' *vorgesetzt ... dies praefix soll doch wol den reinen, ungemischten stamm bezeichnen und scheint unter mehrern söhnen oft nur einem und dem ältesten zu gebühren*
>
> ***5)** heute verwenden wir* eitel, *im sinne des mhd.* gemeit, *von einem der sich seiner vorzüge freut und ihrer bewust wird, und vielleicht dürfte schon in jenem* 'eitel' *vor eigennamen der nebensinn des stolzen, frohen gesucht werden.*

So here is the idea that *eitel* also had the meaning of pureness in old times, was as such used in names of noble men and got from this usage the new meaning of being "proud of someones own 'good parts'".

However, the entry in Grimm's continues. After quoting Goethe

> Göthe sagt 26, 337: konnte man ihm nachsehen, dasz er sich seine persönlichkeit, seine verdienste sehr lebhaft vorempfand, so war kein umgang wünschenswerther zu finden. da mich nun überhaupt das was man eitelkeit nennt, niemals verletzte, und ich mir dagegen auch wieder eitel zu sein erlaubte, d. h. dasjenige unbedenklich hervorkehrte, was mir an mir selbst freude machte, so kam ich mit ihm gar wol überein, wir lieszen uns wechselsweise gelten und schalten.

to illustrate that rather positive connotation  of *eitel* they write

> *an dieses unschuldige, gleichsam berechtigte eitle grenzt aber umschlagend
>
> **6)** die abstraction der ersten bedeutung, eitel im nachtheiligen sinn von inanis, vanus, unnütz, falsch und vergeblich*

and after a lengthy discussion they conclude

> *die phasen unseres* eitel *ergeben sich erst daraus, dasz das helle umdreht ins dunkle, leere, das frohe ins vergebliche. Göthe lenkt also aus dem rechten weg (26, 338) wieder in den unrechten, wenn er schlieszt:* wir Deutschen misbrauchen das wort eitel nur allzuoft, denn eigentlich führt es den begrif von leerheit mit sich und man bezeichnet damit billigerweise nur einen der die freude an seinem nichts, die zufriedenheit mit einer hohlen existenz nicht verbergen kann. *nicht leere, sondern schein, glanz, lauterheit war die urbedeutung, das mhd. gemeit, seinem sinne nach, ursprünglicher als das goth. gamaids, ahd. gimeit.*

I find it difficult to summarize that long entry on *eitel* in Grimm's. To me, it looks like there has been an ambiguity in the meaning of *eitel* for very, very long. How people used it in different times seems to reflect how they perceived themselves within the antagonism of a splendid, yet ever-fading existence.

Answer (score 6):

Dass das Wort »*eitel*« jemals »vergänglich« bedeutet haben soll, konnte ich in keiner Quelle bestätigt finden. Ich habe auch Zweifel an der Richtigkeit dieser Behauptung.

Im Althochdeutschen lassen sich für »eitel« die Bedeutungen »*leer, öde, nichtig, vergeblich*« belegen.

Im Mittelhochdeutschen wird »eitel« in Wendungen »*eitel Gold*« (nichts als Gold), »eitel Freude« (nichts als Freude), aber auch als Vorsatz vor Namen (*Eitel Friedrich* = »einfach nur Friedrich, also ohne Titel«) verwendet.

Gleichzeitig ist auch die Bedeutung »gehaltlos, nichtig« belegt, am prominentesten ausgerechnet in jener Floskel, die du in deiner Frage zitiert hast:

> Alles ist eitel.

Das ist ein Zitat aus Luthers Bibel-Übersetzung (Prediger, Kapitel 1, Überschrift: »Alles Irdische ist eitel«, Pred 1,2 und wortgleich Pred 12,8: »Es ist alles ganz eitel, sprach der Prediger, es ist alles ganz eitel.«)

Darin bedeutet »*eitel*« keineswegs »*vergänglich*«, sondern »*gehaltlos, nichtig, wertlos*«. Und eben diese Bedeutung, die mit dieser Phrase transportiert wurde, führte dann dazu, dass »eitel« immer mehr die Bedeutung »selbstgefällig, eingebildet« annahm.

Quellen:
Duden, Herkunftswörterbuch, 3. Auflage (2001), Seite 175.
[DWDS, eitel](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=eitel)

Comment: "Dass das Wort »eitel« jemals »vergänglich« bedeutet haben soll, konnte ich in keiner Quelle bestätigt finden. Ich habe auch Zweifel an der Richtigkeit dieser Behauptung." - interessant, da ich früher bereits im Deutschunterricht von mehreren Lehrern gelernt hatte, dass "eitel" früher "vergänglich" bedeutete. Ggf. wäre eine separate Frage dazu angebracht.

Comment: Do you say that Gryphius made a reference to Luther then? I never came about such a statement before.

Comment: I guess "nichtig" works fine in the poem of Gryphius. Although "nichtig" is more of a judgement than "vergänglich" which sounds more descriptive to me. In that sense it matters how one should understand "eitel" here.

Comment: @dedoco: »Vergänglich« = It will vanish in the future, it will not last forever. Some day it will be gone and/or be worthless. But now it exists and is bright and valuable. »Nichtig« = It is nothing, Not only in the future, but also now. It is already now worthless. Maybe some people don't realize its actual worthlessness, but anyway its already now  meaningless and valueless.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Do you have a reference for your statement that Gryphius cited Luther?

Comment: @dedoco There is a [Wikipedia article on Gryphius' poem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Es_ist_alles_eitel) that states that the intro of the poem is a reference to Bible phrase that Hubert mentioned.

Comment: @Matthias: Interesting, also concerning Hubert's answer, from the Wikipedia article: `Der dargestellten äußeren Form entspricht der inhaltliche Aufbau. Das vorliegende Sonett ist ein argumentativer Text. In Vers 1 stellt der Dichter eine These auf, die die gleiche Aussage enthält, wie der Titel des Sonetts: Auf dieser Welt ist Alles nur Eitelkeit, hier steht Eitelkeit in seiner alten Bedeutung Vergänglichkeit.` So I guess It is not so uncommon to understand "eitel" as "vergänglich".

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das ist zwar ein langer und interessanter Text, aber ich finde es schade, dass Du den Kern der Frage - den Wandel in der Bedeutung des Begriffs, nur im letzten Satz berührst. - Zu Deinem letzten Kommentar: Wenn man die Dinge vor allem mit Blick auf das Ende sieht, kann man m.E. durchaus zu der Einschätzung gelangen, dass etwas, was vergänglich, also *letztendlich* nichtig ist, insgesamt als nichtig zu betrachten ist. Möglicherweise hat diese Sichtweise zu bestimmten Zeiten dominiert und die Verwendung des Wortes beeinflusst.